# Connecting to mySql with node, error: code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_HANDSHAKE_TWICE', fatal: false

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am making a sign up page and am using express to communicate.
As such, I have an express.js file that when it gets a post it will run a function on my mysql.js file.
Express.js:

```
 //Defining node js libraries
import Express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
const app = Express()
const port = 3000


//Import sql connection function 
import { run_db } from "./mysql.js"


// We are using our packages here
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
 extended: true})); 
app.use(cors())


//Route that handles login logic
app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    const json_db_value = {
        "email": req.body.email.toString(),
        "password": req.body.password.toString(),
        "username": req.body.username.toString()
    }
    run_db(json_db_value)
})


//Start your server on a specified port
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

And here is my mysql.js file

```
//Import mySql library
import mysql from "mysql"


//Runs sql code through db
export let run_db = (insert_values) => {
    //Create connection to database
    const db_connect = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "*******",
        database: "store_user_info"
    })


    //Sql code to execute
    const sql_code = 
    `INSERT INTO Users (email,password,username)
    VALUES (
        ${"'"+insert_values.email+"'"},
        ${"'"+insert_values.password+"'"},
        ${"'"+insert_values.username+"'"}
    )`


    //Run sql code and fetch result
    db_connect.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        db_connect.query("SELECT * FROM Users",(err,result) => {
            if (err) throw err
            for (let i=0;i<Object.keys(result).length;i++) {
                if (result[i].email===insert_values.email || result[i].username===insert_values.username) {
                    console.log("email/username is taken")
                    return
                }else {
                    console.log("email/username is avaliable")
                    insert_values_to_db()
                    return
                }
            }
        })
    })
    let insert_values_to_db = () => {
        db_connect.connect((err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            db_connect.query(sql_code,(err,result) => {
                if (err) throw err
            })
        })
    }
}
```

For the first connect, I make sure the email and username are still avaliable, and then i runs the sql code to insert them into the database. I'm pretty sure that is what's causing the error, but is there another way to run 2 sql connects on the same db?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools) which should be api compatible.  Then do `mysql.createPool` instead of `createConnection`.

Also your code is incorrect.  You shouldn't do `db_connect.connect` multiple times.  That's where your error is coming from.   You should only connect once (but you should probably use a pool because they are better and don't timeout and stuff).

So you should do this:

```
//Import mySql library
import mysql from "mysql2"


//Runs sql code through db
export let run_db = (insert_values) => {
    //Create connection to database
    const db_connect = mysql.createPool({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "*******",
        database: "store_user_info"
    })


    //Sql code to execute
    const sql_code = 
    `INSERT INTO Users (email,password,username)
    VALUES (
        ${"'"+insert_values.email+"'"},
        ${"'"+insert_values.password+"'"},
        ${"'"+insert_values.username+"'"}
    )`


    //Run sql code and fetch result
    let insert_values_to_db = () => {
        if (err) throw err
        db_connect.query(sql_code,(err,result) => {
            if (err) throw err
        })
    }
    if (err) throw err
    db_connect.query("SELECT * FROM Users",(err,result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        for (let i=0;i<Object.keys(result).length;i++) {
            if (result[i].email===insert_values.email || result[i].username===insert_values.username) {
                console.log("email/username is taken")
                return
            }else {
                console.log("email/username is avaliable")
                insert_values_to_db()
                return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now

Comment: @mythiclisp can you upvote me? I'm trying to get to 10k points.

Comment: sorry don't have enough reputation to vote yet